# Rocket Chat Hubot Adapter is not replying back

Tags: javascript, node.js, hubot, rocket.chat

Hi i am running hubot with rocket chat. I have created another user "mybot" having **bot role** and used it and got connected successfully.

Below are my environment variables

```
export ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=''
export LISTEN_ON_ALL_PUBLIC=true
export ROCKETCHAT_USER=mybot
export ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=123456789
export ROCKETCHAT_AUTH=password
```

Hubot is not responding back to me when i am sending any message.

Messages send are visible in **terminal** logs but a return message is not shown from the hubot.

> Screenshot of terminal

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but in my case, it listens in some cases and in some cases it won't. Have you found out why it's happening?